# Qt5: Create valideJSON

Tags: json, qt, qt5

I want to create a JSON like this in Qt: 
I dont find a example or something like this.

```
{
  "ConfigFile": [
    {
      "name": "Car",
      "valueName": "CarValue",
      "actual": {
        "actual": 140
      },
      "upper": {
        "actual": 120.1
      },
      "lower": {
        "actual": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Look at `QJsonDocument`, `QJsonObject` etc. documentation.

Comment: look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html too

Comment: BTW: your braces are not balanced

Comment: @NotYourFan I'd like to add four notes here: **1)** Please try searching for the answer before asking a question - chances are good that a similar question was already answered, giving you a solution without the need to wait for answers. **2)** Provide what you have tried before and where you are stuck - SE is meant to assist you, not for writing your code for you. **3)** If you find an answer useful, consider accepting and/or upvoting it. **4)** Followup question should be asked in a separate question, to allow future users to find them (and not e.g. as comments)

Answer (score 0):

[QJsonObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html), [QJsonValue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html), [QJsonArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonarray.html) and [QJsonDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) should provide what you need.

For example:

```
// Insert key-value pairs in object
QJsonObject jsonObject;
someObject.insert("name", QJsonValue("Car"));
someObject.insert("value", QJsonValue(1234));

// Insert object in array
QJsonArray jsonArray;
someArray.insert(0, someObject);

// Create QJsonDocument to get the json as e.g. QByteArray
QJsonDocument jsonDocument = QJsonDocument(jsonArray);
QByteArray byteArray = jsonDocument.toJson();
```

should give you a QByteArray (roughly) containing

```
[
    {
        "name": "Car",
        "value": 1234
    }
]
```

As mentioned in the comments above, [Qt provides a help page too](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html)

Comment: Thank you, how can i get now one Level lower ? like the example what you poste " Qt provides a help page too" there is one Level lower --> "Adress"

Comment: @NotYourFan you can create a `QJsonValue` from `QJsonObject` and [insert](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#insert) it into another `QJsonObject`. That said, **read** the documentation and try things - should you get stuck then, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: thx, now i get the structure that i want :). Are they a Option to sort my json?

Comment: @NotYourFan This appears to be an entirely separate question. Please open a new question, adding what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.